# my sql query is not working and i couldnt know what went wrong here

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
 public function get_search($start = -0, $limit = null, $postcode = 'default',$branded) {


      if (!empty($branded)) {
            $this->db->join('workshop_brand', 'workshops.id = workshop_brand.w_id');
            $this->db->where('brand_id', $branded);
            $this->db->group_by("workshops.id");
        }
if(!empty($postcodes)){
$this->db->where('`postcode` in (' . $postcodes . ')');
                        $this->db->where("1 order by ", "FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`,'" . $postcodes . "')", false);
}

$query = $this->db->get('workshops', $limit, $start);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
   die();
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

SELECT *
    FROM (`workshops`)
    INNER JOIN `workshop_brand` ON `workshops`.`id` = `workshop_brand`.`w_id`
    WHERE `workshops`.`status` = 1
        AND `postcode` IN (
            2530
            ,2500
            ,2502
            ,2505
            ,2506
            ,2517
            ,2518
            ,2519
            ,2520
            ,2522
            ,2525
            ,2526
            ,2527
            ,2528
            ,2529
            ,2533
            ,2535
            ,2560
            ,2574
            ,2575
            ,2576
            ,2577
            )
        AND 1
    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`, '2530,2500,2502,2505,2506,2517,2518,2519,2520,2522,2525,2526,2527,2528,2529,2533,2535,2560,2574,2575,2576,2577')
        OR `brand_id` = '6'
    GROUP BY `workshops`.`id`

Comment: What did you expect, should the query and? Any errors?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `workshops`.`id`' at line 8

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` should be used before `ORDER BY`,Also `AND 1` is of no use better to remove

```
 GROUP BY workshops.id   
 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(
  postcode,'2530,2500,2502,2505,2506,2517,2518,2519,2520,2522,2525,2526,2527,2528,2529,2533,2535,2560,2574,2575,2576,2577'
)
```

Using Active record you can do this by

```
public function get_search($start = -0, $limit = null, $postcode = 'default', $branded)
{
    if (!empty($branded)) {
            $this->db->join('workshop_brand wb', 'w.id = wb.w_id');
            $this->db->where('wb.brand_id', $branded);
            $this->db->group_by("w.id");
        }
        if (!empty($postcodes)) {
            $this->db->where('`postcode` in (' . $postcodes . ')');
            $this->db->order_by("FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`,'" . $postcodes . "')", "asc" ,FALSE);
        }
             $this->db->select(' w.* ');
             $this->db->from(' workshops w ', $limit, $start);
             $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
             $query=$this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    die();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

If still `$this->db->order_by("FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`,'" . $postcodes . "')", "asc" ,FALSE);` doesn't work then try with

```
if(!empty($postcodes)){
    $this->db->select(" w.* ,FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`,'" . $postcodes . "') AS myorderby ",FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by("myorderby", "asc" ,FALSE);
}else{
    $this->db->select(' w.* ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but Sorry but this still is not working..is join creating any problem in my query..

Comment: Can you please define *not working* what is not working any error you are getting

Comment: i am using codeigniter for running this query.even if i place group by before orderby it gives the same query when last_query is printed..

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY workshops.id' at line 8 ...........................this is the error

Comment: @Rozer can you post the active record query how you are trying this query with active record in your question

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i have kept the active record too.

Answer (score 1):

you have misordered GROUP BY and ORDER BY and OR.

this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`workshops`)
INNER JOIN `workshop_brand` ON `workshops`.`id` = `workshop_brand`.`w_id`
WHERE (`workshops`.`status` = 1
AND `postcode` IN (
    2530
    ,2500
    ,2502
    ,2505
    ,2506
    ,2517
    ,2518
    ,2519
    ,2520
    ,2522
    ,2525
    ,2526
    ,2527
    ,2528
    ,2529
    ,2533
    ,2535
    ,2560
    ,2574
    ,2575
    ,2576
    ,2577
    ) )
 OR `brand_id` = '6'
 GROUP BY `workshops`.`id`
 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`, '2530,2500,2502,2505,2506,2517,2518,2519,2520,2522,2525,2526,2527,2528,2529,2533,2535,2560,2574,2575,2576,2577')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion ..
But this code worked out for me..
really appreciate your support.

$this->db->where("1 group by workshops.id order by ", "FIND_IN_SET(`postcode`,'" . $postc . "')", false);